# how do I "do (condition) for x seconds" (c++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, timer

I am trying to get my finch robot to move forward for a specific amount of time, however I am not sure how to do this. I need this bit of code to execute for 10 seconds and then move on to the next set of instructions.

```
Finch myFinch;
int firstleftSpeed = 10;
int firstrightSpeed = 10;

myFinch.setMotors(firstleftSpeed, firstrightSpeed);
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Maybe calibrating for cpu-cycles versus motor-cycles and doing an empty loop if cpu freq. is independent of temperature and stutter-free? Then adding setMotors(0,0)

Comment: You can ask the current time in the beginning, and then keep asking it , doing usleep for some time, then asking time again until the difference with the first time is big enough.

Comment: The finch API has a sleep function: http://www.finchrobot.com/CDoc/_finch_8h.html

Comment: This is highly platform dependent.  Try searching your platform API or framework for "suspend" or delay or sleep.

Comment: Your question is tagged as `Visual C++`.  Are you making a graphical interface?  If yes, then you should use the Windows UI Timer callback (`WM_TIMER`).  Simply sleeping the program for 10 seconds will cause it to stop responding to the user.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you 10 sec time

```
time_t timer,timer2;
time(&timer);
timer2 = timer+10;
while(timer2 != time(&timer));
```

use header file time.h